# angular ui date picker causing $valid to be set to false

Tags: angularjs, date

I have three radio buttons: Active, Dissolved, Concluded.
If Active chosen then "Active" is stored in the column in the table. 
If Dissolved is chosen then an input with a date picker is displayed. This is the same for Dissolved. Therefore the column is set to nvarchar.
What I'm finding is when I save the screen nothing happens. I stepped through the code and got to this line:

```
if ($scope.addeditregulatoryapprovalForm.$valid)
```

$valid evaluates to false. If I hover over it, I see $error, if I expand that I see date, if I expand that I see an array with one element, when I expand that I see the date that is displaying in the input field.

If what I'm seeing is correct and that it's the date that is causing the issue I just don't know why it's causing an issue. I have to pick a date, even if it's the same date that's already picked, before I can save.

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="col-xs-7 form-inner-group padRt0">
      <div class="clearfix stackDate">
         <input name="DissolutionConcludedStatusDate" id="DissDate1_0" type="radio" ng-model="vm.regulatoryApproval.DissolutionConcludedStatusID" ng-value="1">&nbsp;Active<br />
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix stackDate">
          <input name="DissolutionConcludedStatusDate" id="DissDate1_1" type="radio" ng-model="vm.regulatoryApproval.DissolutionConcludedStatusID" ng-change=vm.setDate() ng-value="2">
            &nbsp;Dissolved&nbsp; <span ng-if="vm.regulatoryApproval.DissolutionConcludedStatusID==2">
              <input class="form-field cal-field" type="text" ng-required="vm.regulatoryApproval.DissolutionConcludedStatusID==2"
                name="DissolvedStatusDate"
                ng-model="vm.regulatoryApproval.DissolutionConcludedStatusDate"
                datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy" close-text="Close" ng-model="vm.regulatoryApproval.DissolutionConcludedStatusDate"><br />
         <div ng-show="addeditregulatoryapprovalForm.submitted || addeditregulatoryapprovalForm.DissolvedStatusDate.$touched">
          <span class="error" ng-show="addeditregulatoryapprovalForm.DissolvedStatusDate.$error.required">Please select a Dissolved date</span>
          </div>
       </span>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix stackDate">
         <input name="ConcludedStatusDate" id="DissDate1_2" ng-model="vm.regulatoryApproval.DissolutionConcludedStatusID" type="radio" ng-change=vm.setDate() ng-value="3">
            &nbsp;Concluded&nbsp;<span ng-if="vm.regulatoryApproval.DissolutionConcludedStatusID==3"> 
          <input type="date" class="form-field cal-field" ng-required="vm.regulatoryApproval.DissolutionConcludedStatusID==3"
              name="ConcludedDate"
               ng-model="vm.regulatoryApproval.DissolutionConcludedStatusDate" 
                datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy" close-text="Close" ng-model="vm.regulatoryApproval.DissolutionConcludedStatusDate"><br />
          <div ng-show="addeditregulatoryapprovalForm.submitted || addeditregulatoryapprovalForm.ConcludedStatusDate.$touched">
          <span class="error" ng-show="addeditregulatoryapprovalForm.ConcludedStatusDate.$error.required">Please select a Concluded date</span>
          </div>
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Is this input date field required? If so then if Active is chosen the date field will be empty and the form will be invalid.

Comment: If the dissolved radio button is selected then the date is required. If the Concluded radio button is selected then the date is required. If the Active radio button is selected then nothing is required. I'm using ng-required. I've added the code to my original post.

Comment: Just another note, I removed the ng-required and still had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was. Because I had to save the date as a string in the database when the form was being saved it was considered invalid because it wanted a date from the datepicker. I had to convert the string to a date when it pulled it from the database before assigning it to the model.